# How do I get current user another property asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation.

AspNetUsers has a column called `AccType` which is int type

If `AccType` is 1 = customer

If `AccType` is 2 = manager.

I can access to current logged user id by `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

I am trying to do if statment as following:

```
    if(User.Identity.GetUserId().AccType == 1){
       redirect to specific page..
    }elseif (User.Identity.GetUSerId().AccType == 2){
     redirect to 2nd specific page..
    }
```

`User.Identity.GetUserId().AccType` this is now working.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I assume GetUserId returns a UserId and not an Object?

Comment: why dont you use `Roles` instead of this?

Comment: Just because I have a another purpose...

Comment: You can use claims as described in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602626/user-identity-name-is-returning-username-instead-of-name/44604041#44604041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.Identity.GetUserId()` returns the id of the currently logged in user. However, if you want to access its properties, you need to get the actual user object. One way to to this is the following:

```
var userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = this.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(userId);
```

A more convenient way will be to make a property for the ApplicationUser in your controller and then to reuse the code.

Property:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return this.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}
```

Getting the user:

```
var user = this.UserManager
    .FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```