# User.Identity.Name is returning UserName instead of Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, asp.net-identity

I want to display Name of a user instead of UserName in navbar that is in  _LoginPartial Currently I'm using `User.Identity.GetUserName()` for userName but now I want to display Name of the current user.

_LoginPartial is called by the Startup.Auth.cs so I can't run the query on the backend and get the Name of my user so I can only use built-in functions which can run by razor in view.

I have tried all of them but they all are giving me username instead of name of the user.

```
<small>@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name</small>
<small>@User.Identity.Name</small>
<small>@threadPrincipal.Identity.Name</small>
<small>@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name</small>
```

How can I get the name instead of userName

This is the User Table

```
ID
Email
EmailConfirm
Password
Security
PhoneNumber
PhoneNumberConfirm
TwoFactorEnable
LockoutEndDateUtc
LockoutEnable
AccessFailedCount
UserName
Name
Status
Image
```

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Still trying to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Name is a custom field of ApplicationUser (the extended IdentityUser) you'll need to add the field as claim.

If you've used the *template* to setup Identity then you'll find in *IdentityModels.cs* the class ApplicationUser. Here I've added a field 'Name' and added this as claim:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("CustomName", Name));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This code will add a claim 'CustomName' which has the value of the name.

In your view you can now read the claims. Here's an example in _LoginPartial:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        @{ var user = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity; }
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + user.FindFirstValue("CustomName") + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>
```

You can add other custom fields as well as claims.

Comment: I tried it by adding a FirstName and assigned it with name, but then Compiler gave an error that I have to write it in user model and in addUser too.

Comment: i did the same but compiler saying that "IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'FindFirst' and no extension method 'FindFirst' accepting a first argument of type 'IPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Kindly tell me that where should I place this code.  I can't access User in GenerateUserIdentityAsync method.

Comment: You don't have to access User in GenerateUserIdentityAsync since ApplicationUser is the user. You should access User in your Controller or View.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Its working, user.FindFirst("CustomName")?.Value was giving me data like CustomName:Name?.Value.  user.FindFirstValue("CustomName") is giving me the name of my current user. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: I agree, FindFirstValue is the better one. I've updated this in the answer. glad I could help.